# RxJava: Executing another observable from inside first observable under some condition

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have the following

```
Observable<DATA> = getDataFromA();
Observable<DATA> = getDataFromB();

Observable<DATA> = getData();

public void getData() {
/*
   Here I would like to have the following in a single stream:
1. return getDataFromA();
2. after data from A is fetched: if (ConditionForB) then execute getDataFromB() observable. 
I would like to execute it separate but not merge with the stream from getDataFromA() because, this data is not to be provided back to the consumer. It is only to be executed and data stored somewhere. 
*/
}
```

`Observable.concat()` and `Observable.merge()` would join the streams and thus the results from `getDataFromB()` would be received by the subscriber. 
Is there a way so that `getDataFromB() observable` is executed after `getDataFromA()` but without providing direct results to the subscriber.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Observable.flatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) to implement that logic

```
getDataFromA()
    .flatMap(dataFromA -> {
        if (ConditionForB) {
            return getDataFromB()
                .map(dataFromB -> {
                     // TODO handle dataFromB
                     return dataFromA; // or merged result of dataFromA and dataFromB
                });
        } else {
            return Observable.just(dataFromA);
        }
    })
```